# Any good team-chat websites?

Tags: python, collaboration, instant-messaging

Are there any good team-chat websites, preferably in Python, ideally with CherryPy or Trac?

This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612/whats-a-good-freeware-collaborative-ie-multiuser-instant-messenger#46660, but a few primary differences:

1) I very much want to host the server.

2) I don't care if Smileys are included or not in the client.

3) I'd like two options for the users:
   a) Ability to host a private IRC like chat on my Trac page (or link to such a page),
   b) allow remote clients to also interact.

Answer (score 2):

[Campfire](http://www.campfirenow.com/) from 37 signals - the rails guys.

**Edit:** It doesn't meet your requirements but it has some great features...

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't meet the requirements, but it is _cool_!  Thanks for the link. +1.